# What provides libttng on openSUSE Tumbleweed

Tags: opensuse

Title says it all, Thanks in advance. (devel packages needed also).

What provides libttng on openSUSE Tumbleweed

Comment: See also https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-opensuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google worked.

Packages = https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-opensuse

Source = https://lttng.org/docs/v2.10/#doc-building-from-source